# Configuring Analyzer

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I just installed SonarQube to try it out and am trying to setup the Analyzer. Since I just want to trial it, I don't want to setup a separate database. Can I use the embedded database for the Analyzer as well? If so, why is there nothing in the docs around derby in configuring sonar-runner.properties. If I do not configure a database, in sonar-runner.properties does it just default to use the embedded database for Sonar Runner?

Answer (score 0):

By default and in absence of configuration, both the server and runner use a H2 database. While this is very handy for evaluation and will work flawlessly, using a dedicated database is highly recommended on the longer term (for both stability, performance and reliability).